# DOJO 1.8 /dojo/request/iframe is deleting <form></form> when uploading a file

Tags: file-upload, dojo

I'm seeing a really strange behavior under DOJO 1.8.0.  I'm trying to asynchronously upload a file.  The file is uploading just fine and I'm getting the  payload as expected, but when clicking the submit button the  tags and everything in between is inexplicably **deleted**!  It just vanishes.  (NOTE: I've isolated this testing to a test page, so there's nothing else at play that would account for it.  You're looking at the entirety of the code.)

```
require(['dojox/form/Uploader',
     "dojo/request/iframe",'dojo/dom','dojo/on',
     'dojox/form/uploader/plugins/IFrame', 'dojo/domReady!'],
    function(Uploader,iframe,dom,on){

    on(dom.byId("myButton"), "click", function(){
        iframe.post("UploadFile.php",{
            form: dom.byId("myForm"),
            handleAs: "json"
            }).then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }, function(err){}
    );
});


<form method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" data-dojo-type="dojox.form.Uploader"
    label="Select Some Files" id="uploader" />

    <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Any ideas from anyone with DOJO 1.8 experience?  I've been using /dojo/io/iframe just fine with versions 1.6 thru 1.7.  This started happening only with 1.8 using the new /dojo/request/iframe code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this issue to the DOJO-Interest group and it was found to be bug with DOJO 1.8.0. It'll be fixed with the upcoming 1.8.1 release.

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15939

**From the bug report:**

> *The form wasn't getting "eaten", but rather the position was getting set on it and moved out of the viewport because of some faulty logic to check if the form was in the DOM. This has been fixed and should be in 1.8.1.*

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/XD4Dc/1/

The form element is set to have target of dojo's injected iframe. Then form gets like, 'dijitHidden' with abs position -1000 top/left. Cant see why tbh.
There's a fix in the fiddle, add to your callback:

```
with(dom.byId("myForm").style) {
       position = "";
       left = "";
       top = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around, though I agree with you that I honestly don't see why DOJO 1.8's iframe is behaving this way.  While the callback will work in an isolated script, it won't work within my current project.  I'd rather not go back to using the 1.7 codebase as DOJO has already announced that their uploader function is being refactored in their 2.0 codebase.  In the short term, unless I can figure out why we're seeing this behavior, I'm probably going to have to introduce a 3rd party uploader function as a work-around until the DOJO function settles down.